# Sending Core Data Entity To FireBase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, core-data

I have an object in core data and wanted to send the order to firebase.

The model in core data looks like this:

```
    extension CustomerOrder {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<CustomerOrder> {
        return NSFetchRequest<CustomerOrder>(entityName: "CustomerOrder")
    }

    @NSManaged public var reference: String?
    @NSManaged public var orderTotal: Double
    @NSManaged public var orderID: NSObject?
    @NSManaged public var orderDrinks: NSSet?

  }
}
```

From what ive seen firebase likes to follow its own format for transferring models, so I was wondering how I would achieve transmitting this model to my firebase db?

Thanks for any assistance on the approach to take!

Answer (score 4):

1. Fetch data from CoreData. 
   https://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/
2. For each entity, post it to Firebase.
   https://www.appcoda.com/firebase/